# How to convert 3F2M DTS-MA file to opus

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, blu-ray

I extracted a mkv file from BDMV with MakeMKV, using this config. I only keep the main audio file.

[image]

The output mkv has the following tracks:

[image]

How can it be 5.0 when the cover says 2.0 stereo? bluray.com also confirms that my disc has a 2.0 DTS MA track.

And when I try to convert it to Opus, using this command

`ffmpeg -i title00.mka  -acodec libopus -b:a 510000 out.opus`

It gave me a channel mapping error:

`Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.0
      BPS-eng         : 1664621
      DURATION-eng    : 01:33:59.039995008
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 528660
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1173358176
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v27.0.0 ('Metropolis') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-10-12 08:39:46
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
File 'out.opus' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dts (dca) -> opus (libopus))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libopus @ 0x7fc1f8026600] Invalid channel layout 5.0(side) for specified mapping family -1.
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!`

How can I properly extract and convert the audio track to 2.0 Opus? Thanks!